# How to get prior distribution based on confidence interval

Tags: bayesian, mathematical-statistics, confidence-interval, prior

If we have mean value and 95% confidence interval of a parameter. For example, sensitivity = 0.5, CI = [0.2,0.78](as you can see, it is asymmetric)

How to decide the prior distribution?
How to calculate the parameter of chosen prior distribution?

Comment: In R: code `qbeta(c(.025,.5,.975),4.9,5.2)` returns
$(0.2012826, 0.4841307, 0.7745677).$

Comment: @BruceET could you explain what these arguments & output mean in this context?

Comment: Distribution $\mathsf{Beta}(4,9,5.2)$ has about 95% of its probability In inteval $(.20, .77)$ and median about $\eta = .48.$

Comment: Confidence interval procedures do not use prior distributions: please, then, explain what you are trying to ask.